# Ruby : stack level too deep (SystemStackError) maxlimit

Tags: ruby, stack

The following is my sample code:

```
def test(v)
  test(v-1) if v > 0
  p v
end
```

if i call `test(11893)` it is working fine.
if i have `v > 11893`, it is throwing `SystemStackError`.
How to increase the limit for this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MRI has [tail recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923/what-is-tail-recursion#37010) optimization *switched off* by default. But one might [turn it on](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-tco/):

```
RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_option = {
  tailcall_optimization: true,
  trace_instruction: false
}
```

also, the code itself must use tail recursion:

```
def test(v)
  return unless v > 0
  p v
  test(v-1) 
end
```

Comment: Do you know if there's a particular reason why it's off by default?

Comment: @AaronChristiansen nope, unfortunately I have no idea. The wild guess would be: either it’s still experimental or “ruby is not about recursion.”

Comment: The [turn it on](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-tco/) link contains a short section, "A negative side to TCO?" which contains, "Guido van Rossum wrote about why he is against supporting TCO in Python. One major problem he points out is that TCO messes up the stack traces, and therefore makes debugging harder.". That is followed by "...Matz is less opposed to the idea...Ruby allows you to optionally enable it...".